# Emacs cua-mode: ctrl-c on empty line

Tags: emacs

In editors like Visual Studio/Sublime Text I can use ctrl-c on a line to copy the whole line. (without selecting something)
Is this possible in Emacs?

Here is my current config:
https://github.com/r03/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs.d/init.el

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box. However, it's not difficult to add this. Almost.
Unfortunately though, <kbd>C-c</kbd> is typically reserved for other functionality in Emacs, it serves as a so-called prefix key. That is, there are a lot of more complex keyboard shortcuts that actually start with <kbd>C-c</kbd>, followed by some additional key strokes. So you might either have to give up that functionality of complex key sequences, or opt for a different keyboard shortcut for copy-line.

(Even `cua-mode`, which you use, leaves <kbd>C-c</kbd> alone for that reason, unless you first mark a region, i.e., exactly *not* the case you're after.)

Anyway, we can write a short function that copies the current line like so:

```
(defun copy-line ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-ring-save (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))
```

To bind this function to a certain key, say, to <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> (that is, two times <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>), use this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") 'copy-line)
```

Put all of the above in your `init.el` file, and after restarting Emacs you can copy the current line without selecting it first.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand why. I use the whole-line-or-region package now and added this shortcut: (global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") 'whole-line-or-region-kill-ring-save). But I think I will remove C-c as prefix key.